# error in mysql request

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I get the following error: The variable name '@Title' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

```
    public static string PostArticle(Article article)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string query = "INSERT INTO Article VALUES (@Title, @UserId, @Category, @Type, @Contents, @Thumbnail)";
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", article.Title);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", article.UserId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", article.Category);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", article.Type);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contents", article.Contents);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thumbnail", article.Thumbnail);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return "Post Successful";
        }
        finally 
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Might you be trying to re-use an existing `Command` that already has a `@Title` parameter?  Get a new `Command` from your connection with `CreateCommand`, apply your parameter values to it, then execute this new command.

Something like this:

```
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ...";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title);
    // ... etc.
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: It is working now, I should have add at the end, cmd.Parameters.clear(), because this code is not only used once

Comment: I think you should consider actually creating a new command each time.  Or find a better way to refactor this, since it's goofy that you seem to be reusing a command but totally replacing its commandtext and parameter list.